# Linear Gradient to an Image in Nativescript

Tags: nativescript, linear-gradients

I'm trying to apply a transparent Linear Gradient on an image.

I'm using `Angular 7.2.0, tns-core-modules 5.3.1`

Html:

```
<Image src="https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/15525/critters.png" class="imgGrad"></Image>
```

Css:

```
.imgGrad{
    height:80;
    width:150;
    background: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(255,255,255,0), rgba(255,255,255,1));
}
```

This code works fine with `IOS but not with Android`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually expected, iOS supports multiple layers so there will be one separate layer to hold the background gradient above the image. With Android, it's just the background, the background won't be visible when you have the image on top of it.

The solution is to use a separate view above image for gradient.

**HTML**

```
<GridLayout class="container">
    <Image src="https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/15525/critters.png"></Image>
    <StackLayout class="gradient"></StackLayout>
</GridLayout>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    height:80;
    width:150;
}

.gradient {
    background: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(255,255,255,0), rgba(255,255,255,1));
}
```